# Populate onslist programmatically

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm trying to build a simple app using Onsen UI and I've setup an empty list that I want to populate with list items in the ons.ready function.

I have this HTML tag on my page:

```
<ons-list id="deviceInfo"></ons-list>
```

I'm building a list of ons-list-items and replacing the HTML with the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having a controller is real simple though:

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item  ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</ons-list-item>
   </ons-list>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
// When you change the contents of $scope.items in your controller, the View will dynamically change. 
$scope.items = {
    item1 : {
        name : "Hamburgar"
    },
    item2 : {
        name : "Pasta"
    },
    item3 : {
        name : "Potato"
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use AngularJS's ngRepeat directive.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

**html**

```
<ons-list-item  ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</ons-list-item>
```

**script**

```
// When you change the contents of $scope.items in your controller, the View will dynamically change. 
$scope.items = {
    item1 : {
        name : "Hamburgar"
    },
    item2 : {
        name : "Pasta"
    },
    item3 : {
        name : "Potato"
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this? I'm simply trying to create a page with an empty list then populate it with values after everything has initialized. This isn't a data driven app, it's simply a demo application. I don't have a controller implemented - I'm simply trying to write some JavaScript code in the ons.ready function to populate this thing.

in jQuery Mobile for example, you can create an empty list then populate it before making a call to refresh to refresh the list view. Is something like that possible here?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ataru's answer, you can dynamically inject list items to page like in JQuery Mobile by using the "ons.compile" function http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#onscompilefunction.
Here is an example;

```
ons.ready(function() {
  var elm = $("<ons-list-item>Item One</ons-list-item>");
  elm.appendTo($("#deviceInfo")); // Insert to the DOM first
  ons.compile(elm[0]); // The argument must be a HTMLElement object
});
```